# Rendering the AppStore page in HTML

Tags: html, app-store, itunes, mac-app-store

I'm looking for a way that allows me to see the AppStore page in HTML instead of the actual view:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: You want to access the App Store via your browser, not via iTunes..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it may be possible somehow, I doubt that Apple will accept that. I found an [example](http://www.labnol.org/software/browse-itunes-without-installing-software/6657/) that used to work in the past, but seem to be shut down now. I also found a [PHP solution](http://hactheplanet.com/blog/5), but I did not try that myself.

Why don't you just deep-link into the itunes store or the websites of an app on the Apple website?

Comment: what you mean with "deep-link into the itunes store"?

What I'm looking for is to scrape all the iTunes link on a particular section as fast as possible.

Proabably a bot can do it for me...but I'm not very good at coding.

Comment: `scrape all the iTunes link on a particular section as fast as possible` - with which goal in mind? Can you tell **what** you actually want to do instead **how** you want to do it?

Comment: I need to save all the iTunes link on a excel sheet.

For this reason, instead click on each icon, copy the link and paste on excel, I was thinking to rendering the page in HTML and then extract the URLs more easily.

Anyway what I'm looking for is to save all the links of a particular page (as the screenshot that I've posted on the first post) on a excel's sheet.

Comment: Then why don't you use the [Apple website](http://itunes.apple.com/de/genre/ios/id36?mt=8)? Use any link grabber you like and give it the url of the app store you like (country basis).

Comment: you are my hero! I was looking for this section of the app store but without success!

Thank you so so so much!